# Dereferencing a class pointer function in iterator

Tags: c++

I have created a Vector of pointers to a class called Food

```
vector<Food*> items;
```

The class looks like the following:

```
 class Food
 {
   private:
    string name;
    int month;
    int year;

   public:
    void display()
    {
      cout << name << " - " << month << "/" << year << endl;
    }
  }
```

I then have created a function to prompt these items

```
void promptInventory(vector<Food*> &items)
{
   string name;
   int month;
   int year;

   do
   {
      cout << "Enter item name: ";
      getline(cin, name);

      if (name != "quit")
      {
         cout << "Enter expiration month: ";
         cin >> month;

         cout << "Enter expiration year: ";
         cin >> year;

         cin.ignore();

         Food * food = new Food;;

         food->setName(name);
         food->setMonth(month);
         food->setYear(year);

         items.push_back(food);
       }
     }
     while (name != "quit);
```

I'd like to iterate through the vector of pointers and call the display function for all the items but I am unable to dereference them using iterators.

How would I be able to sucessfully iterate through these pointers and call the display function?

Unfortunately,

```
vector<Food*>::iterator iter = items.begin();
while (iter < items.end())
{
  cout << *iter->display() << endl;
}
```

Results in:

```
error: request for member ‘display’ in ‘* iter.__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>::operator-><Food**, std::vector<Food*> >()’, which is of pointer type ‘Food*’ (maybe you meant to use ‘->’ ?)
   cout << *iter->display() << endl;
```

Thank you!

Comment: Why are you using pointers for this code?  Why not simply `vector<Food>`?

Comment: I'm practicing using pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Operator Precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) has got you. `*iter->display()` is interpreted by the compiler as `*(iter->display())` because `->` has precedence over (will execute before) `*`. A cleaner way to look at this is `*((*iter).display())`

1. Dereference iterator to a `Food *`.
2. Attempt to invoke display on the `Food*`. Fails and results in the compiler error.
3. Dereference the result of the call to `display`.

You need to force the execution ordering you want with some brackets: `(*iter)->display()`

1. Dereference iterator to a `Food *`
2. Dereference again to a `Food`
3. Invoke display on the `Food`

Fixing this leads to problem 2: `display` doesn't return anything that can be written to `cout`. Fortunately, `display` does all the printing that is required.

```
while (iter < items.end())
{
    (*iter)->display();
}
```

resolves that problem, but in idiomatic C++ there is a better solution: overload the `<<` operator.

`Food` picks up a `friend` function

```
class Food
{
private:
    string name;
    int month;
    int year;

public:
    void display()
    {
      cout << name << " - " << month << "/" << year << endl;
    }
    friend ostream & operator<<(ostream & out, const Food & food)
    {
        out << food.name << " - " << food.month << "/" << food.year;
        return out;
    }
};
```

Then you can

```
vector<Food*>::iterator iter = items.begin();
while (iter < items.end())
{
  cout << **iter << endl;
}
```

or with a range-based for loop

```
for (auto & item:items)
{
      cout << *item << endl;
}
```

Side note: In addition to practicing pointers, practice [Smart Pointers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory). You'll find them much more useful.

Comment: I thought that initially but I get the following error "error: no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}’ and ‘void’)
       cout << (*iter)->display() << endl;"

Comment: @Young_thug that is a completely different issue. `display()` returns a `void` and you are trying to pass the return value of `display()` to `cout`. That will not work. Simply change `cout << (*iter)->display() << endl;` to just `(*iter)->display();` by itself. `display()` uses `cout` internally

Comment: Shoot. I fixated on the surface problem and missed the actual problem. My apologies, @Young_thug . I will update answer shortly, but the quick fix is display does all the printing you need. There is no need to to `cout`, just call `Display`. `while (iter < items.end()) { (*iter)->display(); }`

Comment: @RemyLebeau You're a boss! Thanks you!

Comment: Thank you @user4581301! You were spot on!